# Why doesn't Collections.Generic.Queue have Synchronized method but Collections.Queue has?

Tags: c#, collections, generic-collections, concurrent-collections

`System.Collections.Queue` class has [`Queue.Synchronized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which returns a thread-safe Queue implementation.

But the generic one, `System.Collections.Generic.Queue`  does not have a `Synchronized` method. At this point I have two questions in mind:

1. Why doesn't generic one have this method? Is it a framework API design decision?
2. How is the queue returned from  [`Queue.Synchronized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is different than [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Synchronized()` method returns a wrapper queue that slaps a lock around every method.
This pattern is not actually useful when writing multi-threaded applications.

Most real-world use patterns will not benefit for a synchronized collections; they will still need locks around higher-level operations.

Therefore, the `Synchronized()` methods in `System.Collections` are actually a trap that lead people into writing non-thread-safe code.

---

The `ConcurrentQueue<T>` class is specifically designed for concurrent applications and contains useful methods that atomically modify the queue.

The concurrent collections package only contain methods that make sense to use in a multi-threaded environment (eg, `TryDequeue()`); they will help guide you to write code that is actually thread-safe.

This is called the [pit of success](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/falling-into-the-pit-of-success.html).

For much more information, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures)

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you can answer to my first question above. Thanks!