# What happens when there is synchronization block around the usage of an object only in one place?

Tags: java

```
Class A {
    private Map<Oject,Object> map;
    public void clear() {
        map.clear();
    }

    public void work() {
        synchronized (map) {
            map.put(new Object, new Object();
        }
    }
}
```

If thread A is in the middle of the `work()` method, does this mean thread B won't block if executing the `clear()` method?

What is the difference between the code above and having this?

```
    public void clear() {
        synchronized (map) {
            map.clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct; this code has a bug.

You need to lock around `clear()` as well; otherwise; you can still end up running `put()` and `clear()` concurrently.

However, you should actually use a `ConcurrentHashMap()` instead.

Comment: or Collections.synchronizedMap )

Comment: @SLaks I feel what he is looking for is Collections.synchronizedMap. because he want s to lock the map if one thread is doing put(..). with Concur..Map, clear() and put() from different threads could go at same time. correct me please if my understanding was wrong.

Comment: Does using a ConcurrentHashMap mean it's safe to remove synchronized blocks? Specifically in relation to retrivals/insertions overlapping with clear.

Comment: Yes, it is safe to remove `synchronized` blocks from a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: @Kent: `Collections.synchronizedMap()` is useless. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14148963/34397

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Why would it? That's the point of the `synchronized` block - and thread B hasn't executed a `synchronized` block. In this case, it's exactly like there was no synchronisation at all.

Answer (score 0):

For each location in which access to the given resource should be controlled you should synchronize.  Your first example will only run in a synchronized manner if it hits a synchronized block (which it doesn't in `clear()`), otherwise it'll continue as normal.  Your lock around `clear()` in the second example will cause thread B to check.